# Add mysql schema to MySQL Workbench?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

If this is a super basic question I apologize; I'm still trying to grok MySQL and my options on interfacing with it.

I'm wondering if I'm able to add the mysql schema to MySQL Workbench? I can see and access it via PhpMyAdmin and the command line. I'm also able to query a mysql table (user, for example) from Workbench itself.

I'm mostly just curious if I can add it to the schema section in the lower left hand side of Workbench. I'm using version 6.3.

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

Edit: To better clarify, I'm just wondering if I can view the schema in Workbench like I can in PhpMyAdmin.

[image]

Comment: You can use workbench for all mysql operations, it is made for that, You just need mysql server(maybe from wamp or any other). Phpmyadmin is also an Option you can use, but go for workbench, its an tool specially made for that is my suggession

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL Workbench by default hides system tables (that is PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA, INFORMATION_SCHEMA and mysql). In the preferences (SQL Editor -> Show Metadata and Internal Schemas) you can enable them. After a restart of Workbench you will get them in the schema tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have phpmyadmin and workbench synchronized. What you could do is to work on a site, and then export the schema